# What is a discriminative feature?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

The concept of "discriminative features" is commonly used in papers, discussions, etc. What does it mean exactly?

Is there a name for the features that aren't discriminative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an image recognition problem of classifying portrait photos as being of men or women.

One discriminative feature could be hair length. Sure, there are men with long hair and women with short hair, but hair length is likely to give a lot of insight into the correct answer.

On the other hand, eye color is unlikely to provide much insight, so eye color would not be a discriminative feature.

“Telltale sign” is too strong to be a synonym of “discriminative feature”, but it’s a related idea. The important concept is that the feature contains information about the outcome—perhaps a lot, perhaps just some, but at least enough to be useful.

Comment: So basically a feature that would be useful in a classifier? I guess it's roughly the same as a feature with a high mutual information with respect to the target?

Comment: You have the right idea in saying that it has to do with high (conditional) mutual information, though you don’t have to have a categorical response variable.

Comment: I say “conditional” mutual information because a feature might have zero mutual information with the outcome, but in one level of a factor, there is a strong positive correlation, while another level of that factor has an equally strong negative correlation. (I suppose that X-shape would be zero correlation instead of zero mutual information, so perhaps you have to do this on a continuum instead of levels of a factor in order to get zero mutual information, but I think the idea is illustrated.)